# Jest in a React-Native project. How to Blacklist or delete duplicate modules?

Tags: react-native, jestjs, lerna

I am trying to set up a `React-Native` project with `lerna`. When I try to run `jest` I face the following error.

```
   The name `setupDevtools` was looked up in the Haste module map. It cannot be resolved, because there exists several different files, or packages, that provide a module for that particular name and platform. The platform is generic (no extension). You must delete or blacklist files until there remains only one of these:

      * `/Users/kevin.amiranoff/project/node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Core/Devtools/setupDevtools.js` (module)
      * `/Users/kevin.amiranoff/project/packages/App/node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Core/Devtools/setupDevtools.js` (module)
      * `/Users/kevin.amiranoff/project/packages/App-exceptions/node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Core/Devtools/setupDevtools.js` (module)
      * `/Users/kevin.amiranoff/project/packages/App-signin/node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Core/Devtools/setupDevtools.js` (module)
      * `/Users/kevin.amiranoff/project/packages/App-ui/node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Core/Devtools/setupDevtools.js` (module)
      * `/Users/kevin.amiranoff/project/packages/App-utils/node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Core/Devtools/setupDevtools.js` (module)
```

Here is my `jest` config in my root `package.json`

```
"jest": {
    "preset": "react-native",
    "globals": {
      "__DEV__": true
    },
    "testRegex": "packages/(.*)/src/(.*)/__tests__/(.*).js?$",
    "transformIgnorePatterns": [
      "packages/(.*)/node_modules/?!(react|react-native)"
         ],
    "testEnvironment": "node"
  }
```

Can anyone explain to me what do I have to ignore and how?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should use the `modulePathIgnorePatterns` to ignore certain directories.
Make sure that only the one you really want to use is not in this ignore list.

Link to documentation:
https://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/en/configuration.html#modulepathignorepatterns-array-string

Comment: Thanks it worked. By the way the option is called `modulePathIgnorePatterns`. You are missing a 's'.

Comment: @KevinAmiranoff facing the same issue on differents packages. could you post your final jest config please ? And how you finded the differents path you had to exclude with modulePathIgnorePatterns ? Thanks

Comment: For future reference, you can add `yarn-cache` and `npm-cache` to `modulePathIgnorePatterns`. For more info, check https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/4682#issuecomment-336304046

Comment: I had same issue i just changed the folder path c:/work/somefolder to c:/work2/somefolder

Answer (score 1):

Put the following in your package.json file:

```
  "jest": {
    "modulePathIgnorePatterns": [
      '.*/node-modules/'
    ]
  }
```

You can find more info about this config option in [Configuring Jest here](https://jestjs.io/docs/configuration#modulepathignorepatterns-arraystring).